# Django: create a model that has a set of values for each day of month

Tags: django, django-models

Suppose I want to create a form that allows a user to enter 2 numeric values for each day of the month. (e.g. count and rate). Since each month has a different number of days, how do I best create this.

Should I create a model that has all of the days prepopulated?

```
class myModel(models.Model):
    user = ...
    day1 = models.DateField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    day1_count = models.IntegerField(default=9, min=0, max=100)
    day1_rate = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=100, decimal_places=2)
    day2 = models.DateField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    day2_count = models.IntegerField(default=9, min=0, max=100)
    day2_rate = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=100, decimal_places=2)
    ...
    day31 = models.DateField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    day31_count = models.IntegerField(default=9, min=0, max=100)
    day31_rate = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=100,
```

or should I create some kind of onetomany field?

```
class myDate(models.Model)
    day = models.DateField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    day_count = models.IntegerField(default=9, min=0, max=100)
    day_rate = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=100, decimal_places=2)

class myModel(models.Modle)
    user = ...
    date = models.OneToMany(myDate)
```

I feel like the later option is better, but I don't know how to flesh it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A model like

```
class PerDateInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    day = models.DateField()
    count = models.IntegerField(default=9, min=0, max=100)
    rate = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=100, decimal_places=2)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('user', 'day'),)
```

will let each user save `count` and `rate` for each calendar date. Maybe that would help?

Comment: This works well conceptually. Now, what happens when you try to put a form on it? I have a form for model=PerDateInfo and when I use 'form.as_p' it shows me only one of the date instances. I need to be able to update all of the date instances for a specific user at once. @AKX How do you refer to all of the date cells in PerDateInfo for a specific user in a form.

Comment: Use a `FormSet`.